# Node / Express - Append information to list when user hits bottom of page using Snoocore (Reddit API wrapper)

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express

I am working on a private application of a food sub reddit, what I'm retrieving some images witha limit of 20 images per view and when the user reach the bottom of the page it loads more information and appends it, like ajax; I'm doing the request server side and using Snoocore which is an API wrapper for Reddit. Snoocore actually provides a method to fetch information of the next page. From Snoocore's documentation:

```
// Instead of an HTTP verb, use a Snoocore helper `.listing`
// It will return a "slice" for a listing that has various 
// helpers attached to it.
reddit('/r/askreddit/hot').listing().then(function(slice) {

  // This is the front page of /r/askreddit
  // `slice.children` contains the contents of the page.
  console.log(slice.children);

  // Get a promise for the next slice in this 
  // listing (the next page!)
  return slice.next();

}).then(function(slice) {

  // This is the second page of /r/askreddit
  console.log(slice.children);

});
```

And this is my code:

```
    reddit('/r/food/hot').listing({limit: 10}).then(result => {
        for (var x in result.children){
            if (result.children[x].data.link_flair_text === '[Homemade]' || result.children[x].data.link_flair_text === '[homemade]') {
                if (result.children[x].data.domain !== 'imgur.com') {

                    if (result.children[x].data.post_hint !== "rich:video") {

                        titles.push({
                            'title': he.decode(result.children[x].data.title),
                            'imgurl': he.decode(result.children[x].data.url),
                            'user': result.children[x].data.author,
                            'submission': result.children[x].data.permalink
                        });

                    }

                }
            }
        }
        console.log(result.children[4].data);

        res.render('index', {
            'titleArr': titles
        });

    });
```

on my Pug template I have:

```
extends layout

block content
    div#wrap
        each i in titleArr
            figure.figure
                img.img-fluid.img-rounded(src= i.imgurl) 

                figcaption.figure-caption.text-center
                    p.text-muted #[i #{i.title}]
                    p 
                        | #[i ―by ] 
                        a(href="http://reddit.com" + i.submission, target="_blank")
                            | #[i /u/#{i.user}]
```

`listing({limit: 10})` here is important because, well, it limits the post retrieved; actually I'm retrieving only 10, by default it retrieves 25; anyway, I'm looking for a way, how i said that when the user reach bottom of the page it loads more post; do I have to do this via client side? Or can I do this via server side in some way? Tell me if I need to explain my issue more in depth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is "infinite scrolling", you basically want to do another request when your user reaches the bottom of the page that has been rendered.

This is going to require you to fire an ajax request when your browser scroll reaches the bottom of the page. If you were to use jQuery, your code would look something like this:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    var win = $(window);


    var parts = location.pathname.split("/");

    // assuming a url like domain.com/reddit/10 where 10
    // is the total number of posts you're showing 
    var pageNumber = parts[3]; //this gives you access to the `10`

    // then add 10 to the current page number and 
    pageNumber += 10

    // use that for your ajax request 
    var url = "http://domain.com/reddit/"+pageNumber; 

    // Each time the user scrolls
    win.scroll(function() {
        // End of the document reached?
        if ($(document).height() - win.height() == win.scrollTop()) {
            $('#loading').show();

            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(json) {
                    // do something with your json of your posts
                    // then hide the loading gif or image.
                    $('#loading').hide();
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

This will fire the ajax request whenever your user reaches the bottom of the page, and paginate correctly. This is only the browser side, though.

You will need to edit your server endpoint slightly as well.

For example, you need to increase your limit dynamically

```
//you could use the req.params method from express to accomplish this
 reddit('/r/food/hot').listing({limit: req.params.limit}).then(result => {
        for (var x in result.children){
            if (result.children[x].data.link_flair_text === '[Homemade]' || result.children[x].data.link_flair_text === '[homemade]') {
                if (result.children[x].data.domain !== 'imgur.com') {

                    if (result.children[x].data.post_hint !== "rich:video") {

                        titles.push({
                            'title': he.decode(result.children[x].data.title),
                            'imgurl': he.decode(result.children[x].data.url),
                            'user': result.children[x].data.author,
                            'submission': result.children[x].data.permalink
                        });

                    }

                }
            }
        }
        console.log(result.children[4].data);

        res.render('index', {
            'titleArr': titles
        });

    });
```

Accessing the `req.params.limit` variable should work. You will need to edit your endpoint definition as well. I'm not sure how you have your server's routing setup right now, but this would be one way you could do it:

```
app.get('/reddit/posts/:limit', function(req, res) {
  console.log('limit is: ', req.params.limit);
})
```

The idea here is that you want to increase the number of items you're fetching with each jQuery request. this is a pretty quick and dirty way of doing so, and I'm making some assumptions about how you're handling the server and what you're using, but this should get you 90% of the way there. Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes, I'd have to change some things on the server side because of the way  that I'm handling it, also because I'm doing this in a single web app. Thanks for the input!